# Accessing checkbox inside a list box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

My code is as below.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBoxMarket"  BorderThickness="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"  CommandParameter="{Binding MarketId}" Tag="{Binding MarketId}" Content="{Binding Market}"  Foreground="#FF3D66BE" Name="chkMarket"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to access the selected and deselected checkboxes in the list on click of save button . I am unable to access chkMarket straight away.   Can anyone help?

Comment: You have the `{Binding Checked}` statement in the code which means that you bind it to a view model and you store the list of them somewhere. What is the DataContext of lstBoxMarket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was 2 way binding i could access the values selected by the checkboxes from the item source of listbox.
 DataTable lstBoxMarketItemSourceDT = ((DataView)lstBoxMarket.ItemsSource).ToTable();

"Checked" column in the data table retrieved gives the updated check box values.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your code I tried something like that

```
                 // find all T in the VisualTree
                 public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) 
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        List<T> foundChilds = new List<T>();

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                foreach(var other in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    yield return other;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your MainWindow

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                           // find all checkboxes in my window
        IEnumerable<CheckBox> myBoxes = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(this);

        int numChecked = 0;
        foreach(CheckBox cb in myBoxes)
        {
            if(cb.Name != "chkMarket")
                continue;


            if (cb.IsChecked == true)
                numChecked++;

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Checked items = " + numChecked);


    }
```

My viewmodel code is

```
   public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Paul", Checked = false });
        _persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Brian", Checked = true });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean Checked { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to see the message "Checked items=1".
Hope this helps

Comment: Whenever you are using the `VisualTreeHelper` chances are that you are doing something *wrong*. In this case one could easily access the needed value via the bound objects, direct access to the controls is rarely ever needed in WPF.